# Thread/Task scheduling and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework-6

Some psychic debugging required:

I have an application which is acquiring data at around 100Hz from an external source. Everything goes fine, the data is acquired at a mean rate of every 10ms with practically no jitter.

The strange problem/symptom I'm seeing is that if I just do one simple (and totally unrelated) 'select' via EF before starting the acquisition, the mean rate goes up dramatically, even if it's on a different thread.

I've tried doing the same select directly using ADO.NET and don't see this symptom.

Note that the 'acquisition' isn't even touching the database: I'm just displaying the current 'id' in a test application.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this kind of problem (before I rip out EF and replace it with Dapper...)

Comment: You are using different EF contexts for those queries? Or, are you using the same context concurrently?

Comment: @usr, sorry I missed out a crucial detail. This happens even if the data isn't being saved at all. i.e. there is no second query.

Comment: How did you measure the mean rate after the select if you only perform the select query and no other query? I probably misunderstood.

Comment: @usr, `elapsed_time/sample_count`.